# Localized way to get the possessive form in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Is there some good library out there that gets the possessive form of a word for multiple languages.

In English

- **John's wall** from the name John.
- **Charles' car**  from the name Charles.

Many languages have similar 'quirks'.

Comment: Possessive form for names ending in an 's' can be written either way (Charles's or Charles') personally I've always believed the 's should be added  -> http://www.edufind.com/english/punctuation/apostrophe.php

Answer (score 4):

What languages do you want to support?
Your idea is very generic, if you plan to support this in any language, it will be mostly impossible. Because a lot of languages have not only different suffix/preffix stuff, but also different order of words.
For example: suppose you have a user named Ivan. You say "Ivan's stuff". But in Russian you have to not only change the name, but put it after the Stuff and add a preposition. So in ruff translation sentence will look like "Stuff of Ivan".
So, if you wish to have this correct, you will have implement quite advanced logic: having different structure of messages for every language.

Comment: That's interesting. Currently is only swedish and english, but it will be more in the future (maybe russian). I was hoping to find a solution that would just scale over different languages without problems. We could write a custom formatter, but since we don't speak all the implemented languages it's a little bit problematic.

One solution is to avoid possessive form altogether